# Is it possible to get an OTRS ticket in bulk for multiple works by the same author?

Tags: wikimedia-commons

I have a lot of images I want to upload to Wikimedia Commons, however I do not own them.

Is it possible to get an [OTRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRS) ticket to validate all of them or should I request a OTRS ticket for each work individually?

Comment: I don't have any experience with OTRS, but from my logic I think they should be separated, or maybe grouped by owner (if possible/known). I think so because there are volunteers who check those things, and it would be easier to split the work. (Unless, if such case is possible, it's like "all or nothing" for the images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [OTRS help page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:OTRS):

> Please send us a clear statement that your Commons account (or some other Commons account) is authorized to license your works, either any work or some set of works, e.g. "My images from event X, 2013-10-15". We will make a note of this for your future uploads.